# Correct syntax to avoid the temporary variable

Tags: perl, methods, syntax

Writing some code, I have a list named `FLAGS` where each element is an array reference where the first element is a method name for some Boolean flag to be set (combined getter/setter).
In preparation to "JSONize" the object I want to omit the flags that aren't set (getter method would return false then).

Part of the code to filter the flag names is (`$self->$n()` calls the method which name is `$n` on object `$self`):

```perl
[grep { my $n = $_->[0]; $self->$n() } FLAGS]
```

(Sorry the original code is highly complex, so I can't provide a complete example)

I tried, but couldn't find out the syntax to avoid the temporary variable `$n` (The error message was like "Can't locate object method "ARRAY(0x1c47418)" via package ...").

Does such syntax exist, and if so, how does it look like?

### Update

While I think the answer could be provided with the information present, I made some very similar minimal working example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MWE;

use constant FLAGS      => (
    ['is_authentic', 1],
    ['is_disabled', 2],
    ['is_fault', 3],
#...
);                                      # flag list

sub new($;$)
{
    my ($class, $flags) = @_;
    my $self = \$flags;

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

# value of a bit
sub _bit_value($)
{
    use integer;
    return (1 << $_[0]);
}

# test a bit
sub _bit_test($$)
{
    my ($val, $bit) = @_;

    return $val & _bit_value($bit);
}

sub is_authentic($) { return _bit_test(${$_[0]}, 1) != 0 }
sub is_disabled($)  { return _bit_test(${$_[0]}, 2) != 0 }
sub is_fault($)  { return _bit_test(${$_[0]}, 3) != 0 }

sub flags($)
{
    my $self = $_[0];

    #return FLAGS;
    return grep { my $n = $_->[0]; $self->$n() } FLAGS;
}

1;

package main;
my $f = MWE->new(2);
print "flags: ", join('|', map { $_->[0] } $f->flags()), "\n";
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] so we see the definitions? It doesn't have to be your complete code. Just make what you've shown runnable.

Comment: `[ grep { $self->${\ $_->[0] } } FLAGS ]`

Comment: @tobyink That works, but maybe explain the trick; is it you are creating a reference first, and then dereference that?

Comment: Yes. The `${\ ... }` is a reference-then-dereference. It's necessary because the Perl parser only allows methods to be either an identifier without a sigil (in the case of `$self->foo` or `$self->Some::Package::foo`) as or a "simple" scalar variable (in the case of `$self->$n`). The `${\ ... }` construct is deemed "simple enough".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a simple scalar is allowed there, so you'd either have use a hack

```perl
$self->${\( $_->[0] )}()
```

or a different approach

```perl
$self->can( $_->[0] )->( $self )
```